# How to get seconds of given timezone - UTC time in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime, timezone

I have a file with lines of the form : `1311597859.567497 y_value_to_plot`. The first token is time since epoch, i.e. unix time. The user wants to call plot_file.pl with this filename and a timezone specification such as "America/New_York" or "Europe/London". Calling gnuplot on this file with `set xdata time; set timefmt "%s"` works but it shows the hours in UTC time. But the user would like to see the local time. So for `1311597859.567497`, without any timezone changes,  gnuplot would show `12:44:19`, but if the user specifies `America/New_York`, he would like to see 08:44:19 in the gnuplot window.
I though a simple fix would be to calculate the offset between utc and the given timezone and subtract that from the token, and then run new plot on this new file.
Hence I was looking for a way to get offset_seconds of UTC from a given timezone in Perl.

Comment: Isn't unix time supposed to be UTC?

Comment: The offset in second varies. There is a 14,400s difference with America/New_York for some date-times, and 18,000 for others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I have unix time".  Normally Unix time is the integer number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT; it's not affected by your local time zone.  For example, the current Unix time is 1311823238.  If you have something other than a number like that, please explain exactly what you have.  Is it a string?  If so, what does it look like?  (It seems very unlikely that you'd have "seconds since the epoch in local time", as @justkt suggests; I don't know of anything that would generate such a value.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*By unix time I assume you mean seconds since the epoch in local time and you are trying to convert to seconds since the epoch in UTC.*

Consider using a module such as [Time::Zone](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-1.20/lib/Time/Zone.pm) or [DateTime::TimeZone](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm) (part of [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.70/lib/DateTime.pm)) to help with such a calculation.

For example with Time::Zone:

```
use Time::Zone;
my $offset_sec = tz_local_offset(); # or tz_offset($tz) if you have the TZ
                                    # in a variable and it is not local

my $time = time(); # realistically it will be the time value you provide in localtime
my $utc_time = $time + $offset_sec;
```

With DateTime and DateTime::TimeZone:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

# cache local timezone because determining it can be slow
# if your timezone is user specified get it another way
our $App::LocalTZ = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'local' );
my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => $App::LocalTZ );

my $dt = DateTime->now(); # again, time will be whatever you are passing in
                          # formulated as a DateTime
my $offset = $tz->offset_for_datetime($dt);
```

**Note that using DateTime you can simply convert a DateTime object from local time to UTC time via `set_time_zone('UTC')` and then format it for gnuplot also.**

To do it all by hand, you can format the output of [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) if you can get to epoch seconds from your local time (perhaps using mktime out of a date/time string).

Comment: Marking this as worked, but unfortunately on the perl installation in RHEL6 both of these don't work. I did not want to CPAN-add it since there might be other dependencies.